# Import on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, import

I am trying to import .xml file to a wordpress blog. Import seems to be successful but no imported contents are displayed on the blog.

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: can you show us the xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

The XML need to be in WXR format.

Export your current posts to see the WXR format. Then use a find and replace to reformat your XML document to match the WXR convention.

Comment: @Far It's sort of a pain... been there